# Using Webpack's Node API, how can I run Webpack on a different directory while using loaders from the CWD?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5, webpack-loader

I need to run Webpack on some arbitrary directory. That directory contains only some TypeScript source code, **but not the loaders used in my Webpack configuration**. So I have this:

```
webpack({
    context: "/some/arbitrary/directory",
    ..., // Some more options here
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
```

However, that causes Webpack to look for the `babel-loader` in the same directory as `context` (/some/arbitrary/directory). That behavior is also documented here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#context.

How can I specify that loaders should be loaded from a different directory?
Or is it simply impossible?

My only hope now is to manipulate the `inputFileSystem` option using [linkfs](https://github.com/streamich/linkfs) or some other nasty hack :-(